# How to change selected nodes width in node editor using python?

Tags: python, scripting, shaders

I am trying to select one node in node editor, then select same type of nodes and change width of all selected nodes using python, this script select same type of nodes but it cannot change its height and width. What should I do?

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'NODE_EDITOR':
        an = bpy.context.active_node
        type = an.bl_static_type

        amn = bpy.context.active_object.active_material.name
        nodes = bpy.data.materials[amn].node_tree.nodes

        for n in nodes:
            if n.type == type:
                n.select = True
                n.height == 159
                n.width == 1000
```

Comment: hello ! please be advised overriding builtin keyword `type` is not recommended and can lead to funky bugs. Cheers

Comment: thank you but I can't understand what "overriding builtin keyword type " means. I want to avoid glitches.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568087/is-it-safe-to-use-the-python-word-type-in-my-code

Comment: I see. I will avoid "type" as a variable. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you can have only one active object and one active material, you can without going through areas:

```
# find active object
obj = bpy.context.object
# find active material
mat = obj.active_material

# find active node
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
active_node = nodes.active

# then loop over the nodes, checking for their types
for node in nodes:
    if node.type == active_node.type:
        # and change select state and width
        node.select = True
        node.width = 600
        # but you cannot change the height
        #node.height = 300
```

Of course, you may add some checks in this code in case no active element exists at a step or another.

Comment: it works! thank you. only active node's width and height can be changed then..

Comment: you can change width of any node... what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, yours goes through active_material path but mine isn't. That's why I can't change node's width? amn = bpy.context.active_object.active_material.name  nodes = bpy.data.materials[amn].node_tree.nodes If I touch nodes data from this path,node data can not be edited?

Comment: never mind. it should be n.width = 1000,not n.width == 1000. thanx lol.

Comment: I think `an = bpy.context.active_node` may throw an exception in your code.

Comment: ok. I will check.